# Multiple Box-Plots in one plot using matplotlib with subgroups

Tags: python

I have 2 fields "market_cap" and "debt_ratio" where I'm using the pandas cut function in order to create 5 subgroups based on market_cap.

I'm interested into create 5 box-plots (for each subgroup ) but the data to be displayed is the debt_ratio.

```
cleaned_data = ( cleaned_data.groupby( pd.cut( cleaned_data['market_cap_(in_us_$)'], 5      ) )['market_debt_to_capital_ratio'] )

# Create a figure instance
fig = plt.figure( 1, figsize = ( 9, 5 ) )

# Create an axes instance
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 )

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot( cleaned_data )

# Save the figure
fig.savefig( 'fig1.png', bbox_inches = 'tight' )
```

However, I'm getting the following error

```
File "C:...\box_plots.py", line 29, in <module>
bp = ax.boxplot( cleaned_data[1] )
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 489, in __getitem__
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Are you sure this has something to do with the actual plotting? if you  place `a = cleaned_data[1]` as your second line of code - will it throw an exception?

Comment: The answer below solved my problem. Beside that, I'm not fully understanding your suggestion of placing "a = cleaned_data[1]". I running the code above again and now I'm getting:                         
    File "C:\...\box_plots.py", line 32, in <module>
    bp = ax.boxplot( cleaned_data )
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line  5967, in boxplot
    if not hasattr(x[0], '__len__'):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",  line 489, in __getitem__
    raise NotImplementedError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce a boxplot by adding the individual groups into a list.

```
test = []
for name, group in cleaned_data:
    test.append(group)
boxplot(test)
```